# Nginx http redirect to https when https proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect, proxypass

I have an nginx configuration which redirect from http to https, but on the https side the location / {} include a proxy_pass to a Go service.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name *.domain.com domain.com;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  server_name auth.domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:PORT;
  }
}
```

But this is not redirect the location where I setted proxy_pass.

**UPDATE:**

I want to redirect from http to https. There is few location which pointing static files (html), and there is a /api and the / which shows below. When I want to redirect from http to https in the statis files location its redirect, but for the locations which have a proxy_pass in it just loading on http and nothing happened.

Comment: You should probably try to add `proxy_redirect http://localhost:PORT https://auth.myminifactory.com;` to your `location` for the `ssl` server config.

Comment: What do you mean? I tried to add, but still not redirect.

Comment: It's completely unclear what is the problem

Comment: Please clarify what exactly happens, and what exactly you expect to happen.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: I know you think you clarified the problem, but you haven't. Perhaps you should write some pseudocode to show us what you mean.

Comment: @Tim I don't know what you mean under pseudocode. This is my whole nginx configuration what I'm using. So currently what you see on the snippet I'm using it on live of course I changed the domain names. The problem is what I mentoined. The nginx not able to redirect to the location which include only a proxy_pass. I can't write about more, because this is the problem and I'm looking for someone how know, why this configuration not redirect from http to https on locations where it only have a proxy_pass.

Comment: I'm not sure if English is your first language, but your question is unclear. I've read your question and comments three times, I don't know what your problem is or what the end goal is. I suggested pseudocode because you're a developer and figured that might be easier for you. Perhaps you mean "I want to redirect all my subdomains from http to https on the auth subdomain, other than the http://example.com/api url which should be served from http". Perhaps you could describe the problem to someone around you and have them update the question.

Comment: I do note that your https server is on the auth subdomain but your http server isn't redirecting there. In the http block that would be "return 301 https://auth.domain.com$request_uri;"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the configuration i use for redirecting HTTP to HTTPs :

```
server {
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}
server {
    ...normal HTTPS conf ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the configuration as mentioned below:

```
# Force all users to https://www.example.com
server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
} 
server {  
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name example.com; 

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com.pem;         // path of pem or crt file for the domain   
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com.key;     // path of key file for the domain
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;   
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log    /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;    
    
    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host www.example.com;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:PORT;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:PORT https://example.com;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Single server definition is enough:

```
upstream backend {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080; # replace with actual address and port
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

  server_name *.domain.com domain.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/*.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/*.domain.com/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }

  # rewrite to https
  if ($scheme = http) {
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}
```